# How to use sendDirect() function in other class to send message?

Tags: omnet++

When I try to call sendDirect() function like this:

```
cSimpleModule *module = new cSimpleModule();
module->sendDirect(msg, nodeId,"io");
```

The compiler returns this error :

[image: omnet sendirect function error]

According to Omnet++ documentation, this class has an sendDirect() function: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api//classomnetpp_1_1cSimpleModule.html

I am trying to use `sendDirect()` function in standard cpp file. What I mean by standard cpp file is that it doesn't have relation with ned file (it doesn't have a ned file module).

When I use `sendDirect()` function in cpp file which has a module that defined `Define_Module("moduleName")`, `sendDirect()` function directly works. It works without create any object to using it.

My main problem is, why can't I use `sendDirect()` function in cpp file which doesn't have a module (related ned file)? If it is possible, how it can be?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by sending a message this way? How did you define nodeId?

Comment: I am trying to simulate some attacks in Omnet. For that, I create new class. Its name `Attack.cpp`. I defined functions for some attacks in that class. For example; ddos(), sinkHole() etc. When an malicious node receives a message in the handleMessage() function, I call `ddos()` function like this `attack->ddos()` but, this function can not send message. Because, I can not use `sendDirect()` function in this function. Whenever i use `sendDirect()` function, I am getting error. I create `Attack.cpp` class only for increasing the code readability. It is not an omnet module that has ned file.